# mysql db enterprise upgrade from 5.5.42 to 5.7.11

Tags: mysql, upgrade, dbmigrate

All,

Our product uses Mysql enterprise db. currently at 5.5.42 but planning to upgrade to 5.7.latest. What changes should I expect to see ?

I'm interested in : 
1) Performance impacts
2) Broken behavior
3) Changed behavior
4) Improvements -- functional and performance-wise

Is it advised to 1st upgrade our product to use 5.6.x and then next to 5.7.x OR directly to 5.7.x and then test/QA from there ? Any inputs will be valuable.

Comment: 2-4 are listed in the various release notes, 1 is also hinted in release notes, however configuration and use have a huge impact on performance, so it is extremely difficult to answer this point.

Comment: how many release notes do I need to look at for understanding the impact between 5.5.42 and 5.7.11 ? It would have been nice if oracle/mysql had an easy way to compare 2 releases.

Comment: why negative votes ? I'm seeking for objective advice, after all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Performance

Performance gains in 5.7 can be achieved only on high loaded systems. If you have less than 40-60 parallel executions, then expect small performance fall around 10%. This is very system- and load-dependent. Always test yourself!
Here is good  MySQL 5.7 performance test done by Percona: https://www.percona.com/blog/2016/05/17/mysql-5-7-read-write-benchmarks/

### Changed and broken behaviour, Improvements

There were a lot of changes in 5.7. Check this link for complete list: http://www.thecompletelistoffeatures.com/

I would mention the following changes, that one should think of during upgrade:

1. SQL_MODE was changed. It is good for new installations, but for old systems most probably you will have to set it back to the old value.
2. First GA release had password expiry, but after complaints it was disabled in 5.7.11. So nothing to worry about now.
3. SQL optimizer was changed a lot. Queries should run faster now, but I expect, that some could run slower. The most time should be spent on queries testing on the new version!

Here is good overview of all changes affecting upgrade to 5.7:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/upgrading-from-previous-series.html

### Upgrade

There are two ways to upgrade: using mysql_upgrade and mysqldump.

1. With mysql_upgrade go with one version at a time. There is no need to test intermediary version. Test only final version.
2. With mysqldump go directly to 5.7. It is advisable to skip **mysql** database. Users can not be migrated with mysqldump, use grant statements.

For further information read this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/upgrading.html

Comment: thank you. Can you share more info about mysqldump option.

Comment: What is your exact question about mysqldump? Here is good link for example: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/30974/backup-and-restore-mysql-database/31023#31023.

Comment: So, the sequence is 1) shell> mysqldump --master-data=2 --all-databases > dumpfile 2) uninstall old mysql version 3) install new mysql version 4) shell> mysql < dumpfile.   Does that look ok ?

Comment: Yes, that will work, but don't forget to run mysql_upgrade at the end (step 5). As I mentioned mysql database was changed in 5.7, and with the mysqldump you will get wrong schema. mysql_upgrade will fix it.
Also you may add --routines  and --events flags to mysqldump, if you have procedures or events.

Answer (score 2):

There are tremendous amount of change between 5.5 and 5.7. It's simply not practical to enlist them all here. I'll try to highlight the most important ones. Obviously there are also a lot of [new features introduced](http://mysqlserverteam.com/whats-new-in-mysql-5-7-generally-available/) (GTID, semi-sync replication, JSON support, virtual columns etc.).

1) Performance

You should expect performance gains since 5.6 and 5.7 improved a lot in mutex handling therefore less contention is expected.

Also scalability improvements were done so you can scale your servers up further and performance/query capacity follows for longer than before.

There were a lot of change in the optimizer. So make sure to check your queries.

At the end of the day you should always check your own case with the your own application.

2+3) Changed and broken behaviour

Password expiry. In 5.7 passwords can have expire time. Just something to be aware of.

Password management commands have changed so make sure you check them before you get surprised by having your automation broken.

Since optimizer and the cost model changed a lot some queries might get executed differently.

Two parameters I would mention specifically that caused some headaches for us: Look into the `optimizer_switch` and decide what you turn on and off. `range_index_dive_limit` default value was raised from 10 to 200 by default in 5.7.4+. Since I see this parameter is rarely being set in any my.cnf this new default might affect you big time.

4) Improvements

A lot. As I wrote above there are plenty of new features and scalability, performance improvements that were meant to server you better.

5) Upgrade path

Yes, it's best to do one major upgrade at a time, test and when everything's working you can do the second major upgrade.

Comment: Thank you. @Károly Nagy : So, is it not possible to upgrade from 5.5 export directly to 5.7 ? Windows OS usually allowed for 2 levels below to upgrade to the latest level.

Comment: It may be possible but certainly not recommended. According to Oracle themselves: " if you currently are running MySQL 5.5 and wish to upgrade to a newer series, upgrade to MySQL 5.6 first before upgrading to MySQL 5.7" http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/upgrading.html#upgrade-paths

Answer (score 0):

**Compatibility** - The issue that would be your greatest concern when upgrading. Because your codes/syntaxes are made with lower version, expect them to behave differently for some of them will be invalid or would not be recognized with the newer version (great impact will be occurred if you jump to a very far higher version).

Normally, you'll get improved performance, security, etc with newer versions but you need to bend your codes/syntaxes to cope with new functions and features.